# Как передать динамические данные из Service в Activity?

Tags: android, многопоточность, service, broadcast-receiver, android-handler

Есть задача, по нажатию кнопки запускать `Service` который будет выполнять действие в фоне, с этим проблем нет. Проблема в том что я ни как не могу отследить состояние `Servis'а`, т.е. вывести информацию о работе в основной UI поток `Activity` и менять данные в `TextView`.
Что лучше использовать в такой ситуации? Вроде для этого используют `Handler` или `BraodcastReceiver`, но примеры что я пробовал не подходят так как требуют создания доп. классов, например: `BroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver`, мне не удается адаптировать это для моих целей. Может у кого есть пример?

Comment: Я делаю так. В MainActivity объявляю public static volatile int var (например), а в сервисе добавляю её как  import static (package name) var. Тут почему-то все ругаются на такой манёвр, но моё приложение уж сколько лет так работает без проблем.

Comment: Тут без вариантов лучше подходит BraodcastReceiver. Никаких новых классов не нужно создавать.

Comment: @DrMcSheen не пойму как это реализовать, может у вас есть пример кода?!

Comment: @Style-7 просто все примеры что я видел включают в себя приемник выделенный как отдельный класс, а как этот приемник сделать в активности не понимаю

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В активности создаем объект `BroadcastReceiver` и регистрируем/отменяем регистрацию.

```
BroadcastReceiver br = new BroadcastReceiver(){
    @Override
    public void onReceive( Context context, Intent intent ){
        if( intent.getAction().equals( ServiceMy.ACTION_UPDATE ) ){
           // Здесь можно обновлять UI
        }
    }
};

@Override
protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction( ServiceMy.ACTION_UPDATE ); // Можно добавить больше действий
    registerReceiver( br, filter);
}

@Override
protected void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    unregisterReceiver( br );
}
```

В сервисе просто посылаем сообщение. Нужные параметры можно передать через `Intent` методом `putExtra`.

```
static final String ACTION_UPDATE = "UPDATE";

....
sendBroadcast( new Intent( ACTION_UPDATE ) ); // там где нужно обновить активность
...
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь